# how to get input from user at run time in oracle?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

hi friends i need to get input from user at the execution of pl/sql block i have tried this one:

```
Accept x number prompt 'enter variable'
set serveroutput on
declare
begin
dbms_output.putline('ut entered value id'||x);
end;
/
```

but i got error as:

Error starting at line 3 in command:

```
declare
begin
dbms_output.putline('ut entered value id'||x);
end;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 44:
PLS-00201: identifier 'X' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

can anybody help me!

Comment: You need to reference a sqlplus variable with an Ampersand in the pl/sql block, ie - dbms_output.putline('ut entered value id'||&x);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL*Plus [substitution variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref453) are referenced with an ampersand `&`:

```
SQL> Accept x number prompt 'enter variable:'
enter variable:1234
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2  begin
  3  dbms_output.put_line('ut entered value id:'||&x);
  4  end;
  5  /
old   3: dbms_output.put_line('ut entered value id:'||&x);
new   3: dbms_output.put_line('ut entered value id:'||      1234);
ut entered value id:1234

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what your after but maybe...

`Select * from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where grantee = '&Grantee';`

Comment: no no,i need to get value from user in my procedure for further processing!

Comment: parameterized procedure then.  What UI is the user responding from?  oracle forms? PHP? some other language?  when you call the procedure from that UI you pass parameters in.   I guess I"m just not following the question yet.